# How can I see if Windows is refusing to trust a TPM?

Tags: windows, tpm

I've been fighting with my motherboard's manufacturer to get a TPM I bought from them to work. In UEFI/BIOS I can see the TPM and set its state to enabled, but in `tpm.msc` it just reads that no compatible TPM was found (see screenshot), and it does not appear in Windows Device Manager either.

[image: tpm management panel showing no tpm found]

*Note that this alert is the exact same if you have the TPM installed or not*

[image: Device Manager]

After RMA-ing the TPM and having the swapped unit still not work, I'm pretty confident that the issue is with Windows refusing to trust the TPM due to out of date or insecure firmware. The problem is, how can I be sure of this?

I've looked through Windows Event Viewer to try and find some event that shows that Windows sees the TPM, but doesn't accept it, but couldn't find anything.

Is there any way I can test this TPM against Windows and see that it isn't trusted?

Comment: What is the output of: `wmic /namespace:\\root\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftTpm path Win32_Tpm get *`

Comment: @GregAskew `No Instance(s) Available`, which is the same output I see on a computer that doesn't have any TPM installed.

Comment: Doesn't sound like trust, sounds like Windows is not recognizing the hardware or there is a hardware problem. What model server and TPM chip is it, and what TPM spec versions are displayed in the BIOS?

Comment: Does the TPM appear in Device Manager?

Comment: @HarryJohnston it does not, as stated in the question.

Comment: @GregAskew It's an Asus TPM-L R2.0. Just an infinion TPM. Other than controlling the state and the action, there's no version information in the BIOS.

Comment: Any unrecognized devices showing up?

Comment: @HarryJohnston No, I'll update the post to include a screenshot of the device manager.

Comment: This may be (another!) silly question, but how is the TPM physically connected?  I've only ever seen TPMs that are built into the motherboard.

Comment: @HarryJohnston There's a 20-pin header on the motherboard where it is plugged in.

Comment: Asus TPM-L R2.0 appears to be a TPM 2.0 device.   Does your UEFI firmware support TPM 2?   What is the output  of the `ver` coomand at your UEFI shell prompt?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 the revision was 2.4

Comment: Version 2.4 should hande TPM 2.0 without an issue so that does not seem to be the problem.  If  you can build UEFI utillities, have a look at  `ShowTPM2` and `ShowTCM20` at https://github.com/fpmurphy/UEFI-Utilities-2016/tree/master/MyApps

Comment: Powershell will tell you with `Get-Tpm`.